# Asset change doesn't reflect to my dev environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, aws-cloud9

I recently moved to AWS c9 because c9 was shut down by force.

I'm having a problem with the asset pipeline. Whenever I change something on css and run my app, I don't see any change.

When I used cloud9, I had no problem at all.

Can somebody help me, please??

I'm stuck as I couldn't resolve from many different resources and taking a lot of time.

Ruby - 2.3.6

Rails - 4.1.8

AWS C9 ubuntu

I tried

```
config.assets.compile = true  in dev

rake assets:clean

Removed the public assets  //  tmp cache
```

... none of them worked for me.

My Application.css.scss file

```
 @import 'modules/_mixins.scss';
@import 'modules/_breadcrumbs.scss';
@import 'modules/_buttons.scss';
@import 'modules/_feature.scss';
@import 'modules/_fonts.scss';
@import 'modules/_footer.scss';
@import 'modules/_forms.scss';
@import 'modules/_general.scss';
@import 'modules/_grid.scss';
@import 'modules/_language_dropdown.scss';
@import 'modules/_navbar.scss';
@import 'modules/_mobile-nav.scss';
@import 'modules/_sections.scss';
@import 'modules/_spacing.scss';
@import 'modules/_tables.scss';
@import 'modules/_typography.scss';
@import 'modules/_custom.scss';
@import 'modules/_w3.scss';
@import 'modules/_color.scss';
```

I don't see any error message but I also don't see any change that I made on CSS.

Comment: Have you tried adding ```*= require_tree .``` to your ```application.scss```?

Comment: @B-M Yes, It didn't work.

Comment: Okay, I found why. After changing css and remove web browser cache, it reflects the css change. My concern now is how to disable being affected by the cache??

Comment: disabling the browser cache did not worked for me